# SELECT AVG subquery with condition

Tags: sql

I have the follwing tables:

**`teachers`** , **`teacher_rating`** and **`cities`**.

---

**`teachers`** has the following columns:

`teacherID,location,name,othercities,status`

---

**`teacher_rating`** has the following columns:

`ratingId, teacherId,content,ratingNumber,created,status,userName`

---

**`cities`** has the following columns:

`id,name`

---

I'm trying to sort all of the teachers (rows from `teachers` where `status=0`) by their average rating, this is my php variable with the SQL:

```
$q="SELECT
    *,
    AVG(pr.ratingNumber) AS rating_average
FROM teachers as p
LEFT JOIN teacher_rating pr
ON pr.teacherId = p.teacherID
WHERE p.location=(SELECT `name` FROM `cities` WHERE `id`=:location) AND p.status=0 OR p.othercities REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]](', :location,')( |)[[:>:]]') AND p.status=0
GROUP BY p.teacherID
ORDER BY rating_average DESC
";
```

It works fine, the only problem is that the rating average includes ratings from the `teacher_rating` table where `status=1`, I want it to calculate the average rating only using the values from `teacher_rating` where `status=0`.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding pr.status=0 in the join?

```
ON pr.teacherId = p.teacherID AND pr.status=0
```

Comment: p.location isn't the problem,the problem is that I want to show the teacher even if pr.status=0, just not to consider the pr.ratingNumber in the rating_average where pr.status=0.

Comment: @itailitai Then why don't you add pr.status=0 in the join?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `AND` and `OR`, so you should use parentheses.  I think you intend:

```
WHERE p.status = 0 AND
      pr.status = 0 AND
      (p.location = (SELECT `name` FROM `cities` WHERE `id`=:location) OR 
       p.othercities REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]](', :location,')( |)[[:>:]]')
      )
```

Comment: I want to show the teacher even if pr.status=0, just not to consider the pr.ratingNumber in the rating_average where pr.status=0.